# Help solving composite function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

The problem is as follows:

> Let $f(x) = \frac{1}{1-x} $ for $x \in\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0,1\}. $ Find $(f \circ f)(x)$.

*My approach:*

$$\begin{align}f\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right) &= \frac{1}{1 -\frac{1}{1-x}}\\\\
&= \frac{1}{\frac{1-x}{1-x} - \frac{1}{1-x}}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{\frac{-x}{1-x}}\\\\
&=\frac{1-x}{-x}\end{align}$$

But the answer I get is wrong, I'm wondering what did I do wrong?

Comment: Your answer is correct. It’s equal to $\frac{x-1}{x}$, by multiplying the numerator and denominator by $-1$.

Comment: @Loobear23 why would I multiply by -1 ?

Comment: Well, you don’t need to. What is it that makes you think your answer is wrong?

Comment: @Papaya-Automaton what is the given answer (in case you know it)?

Comment: It was a multiple answer question and $\frac{x-1}{x}$ it's there but not the answer I came up with.

Comment: $\frac{x-1}{x}$ is the same function as the one you worked out

Comment: Very well, I understand now.